# React-Native-Admob show test banner but real bannerid doesn't work

Tags: reactjs, admob, native

the problem is the same in the title.. I tried to add a little banner in bottom. The basic test banner of admob works perfectly, i made a real banner in the site and copied the unitID and bye bye, nothing appear. Maybe i need to add AppID somewhere?

Here my code...

```html
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { View } from 'react-native';
import { 
    AdMobBanner
  } from 'react-native-admob';



export default class Banner extends Component {
    render() {
        return(
            <View style={{ marginTop: 40 }}>
            <AdMobBanner
                
                adUnitID="ca-app-pub-7484134098633054/8798606096"
                testDeviceID="EMULATOR"
                onAdFailedToLoad={error => console.log(error)} 
                adSize="fullBanner"/>
                            
            </View>
        );
    }
}
```

And here, my console.log:

```html
Running application "BurpSimV3" with appParams: {"rootTag":41}. __DEV__ === true, development-level warning are ON, performance optimizations are OFF
blob:http://localhost:8081/842d3eb6-8510-49bb-b3ac-0443ff0d526d:62578 Error: Internal error, an invalid response was received from the ad server.
    at createErrorFromErrorData (blob:http://localhost:8081/842d3eb6-8510-49bb-b3ac-0443ff0d526d:62772)
    at AdMobBanner.handleAdFailedToLoad (blob:http://localhost:8081/842d3eb6-8510-49bb-b3ac-0443ff0d526d:62717)
    at AdMobBanner.proxiedMethod (blob:http://localhost:8081/842d3eb6-8510-49bb-b3ac-0443ff0d526d:36853)
    at Object.invokeGuardedCallback (blob:http://localhost:8081/842d3eb6-8510-49bb-b3ac-0443ff0d526d:4173)
    at Object.invokeGuardedCallback (blob:http://localhost:8081/842d3eb6-8510-49bb-b3ac-0443ff0d526d:4242)
    at Object.invokeGuardedCallbackAndCatchFirstError (blob:http://localhost:8081/842d3eb6-8510-49bb-b3ac-0443ff0d526d:4245)
    at executeDispatch (blob:http://localhost:8081/842d3eb6-8510-49bb-b3ac-0443ff0d526d:4416)
    at executeDispatchesInOrder (blob:http://localhost:8081/842d3eb6-8510-49bb-b3ac-0443ff0d526d:4436)
    at executeDispatchesAndRelease (blob:http://localhost:8081/842d3eb6-8510-49bb-b3ac-0443ff0d526d:4531)
    at executeDispatchesAndReleaseTopLevel (blob:http://localhost:8081/842d3eb6-8510-49bb-b3ac-0443ff0d526d:4544)
```

I'm going crazy :'(

Comment: Same issue, have you found the solution?